# sending object from MainWindow to the UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've just scratched wpf and I have hopefully simple question.

How would you manage situtions like this

Inside ui wpf project there is MainWindow and two user controls. On default action I want to display usercontrol1 and usercontrol2 to be hidden. Both of this controls should have access to the repository instance for managing further work. Should I work with this repository instance with adding dependency property in each control or should I create viewmodel and work with viewmodel.

about binding

Let's say that I want to display inside MainControl listview some list of data. Please correct me

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
 <my:MainControl x:Name="mainControl" Repository="{Binding}" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ICarRepository repository = new CarRepository();
   DataContext = repository;
}
```

**MainControl.xaml.cs**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RepositoryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Repository",
            typeof(ICarRepository),
            typeof(MainControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ICarRepository Repository
        {
            get { return (ICarRepository)GetValue(RepositoryProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RepositoryProperty, value); }
        }

public MainControl() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = Repository.CountData();
}
```

**MainControl.xaml**

```
<Label Name="lblCountBooks" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

as I understand this should be fine, but I have one major obstacle here. I dont know how to pass repository instance from MainWindow to the MainControl. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: In theory your label content should end up being CarRepository.ToString(), also "how to pass repository instance from MainWindow to the MainControl" shouldn't be an issue as the DataContext will bubble up from MainWindow.

Comment: please disregard label lblCountBooks, what is important to me is how to receive repository instance at MainControl, with these code above I'm getting Repository as null at MainControl constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in your comment, the `Repository` is null in your `MainControl()` constructor until after the constructor finishes and binding has occurred.

Instead, rely on the binding in the `MainWindow`. Also use a property on the `ICarRepository` instead of the `CountData()` method.

```
<Label Name="lblCountBooks" Content="{Binding Path=DataCount}"/>
```

assuming

```
public interface ICarRepository : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int DataCount { get; }
}
```

If your `MainControl` *must* be explicit about accepting the `Repository`, you should respond to the `DependencyProperty` being set and update the `DataContext`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RepositoryProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Repository",
                                    typeof(ICarRepository),
                                    typeof(MainControl),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(OnRepositoryChanged));

private static void OnRepositoryChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ICarRepository repository = e.NewValue as ICarRepository;
    ((MainControl)d).DataContext = repository;
}
```

When the binding from the `MainWindow` sets the `Repository` property of your `MainControl`, `OnRepositoryChanged` is called back to notify you. This is the correct tim eto update your `DataContext`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting the DataContext of the MainControl in the Constructor of the MainControl. This, in effect, breaks the external binding.

Binding from the control owner to the control occurs after the construction of the control. For the binding to work, both the owner of the control and the control need to have the same DataContext.

Remove the binding from the Constructor of the Main Control and add it to the root content node. This means that the  node will have the DataContext of the owner, allowing binding from the control owner to work, while the content will have a DataContext that is the UserControl.

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type this:UserControl2}}, Path=Repository}">
        <!-- content -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have removed all the namespacing for brevity.

I hope this helps